# Delayed_Job NoMethodError when using Nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job, nomethoderror

I'm having trouble implementing the **Delayed_Job_Active_Record** gem in my Production Environment with Nginx.  The user submits a 'Contact Us' form, the relevant controller action is called by Nginx and the following line of code fails:

```
@contact.delay.send_contact_form
```

Where the relevant method is:

```
def send_contact_form
   ContactMailer.contact_us(self).deliver
end
```

**Development Env: OK**

- On my local machine I have the pages served by Webrick.  Everything runs fine, the delayed jobs go through the 'Delayed_Jobs' table and emails are sent.

**Production Env - Rails Console: OK**

- On the server if I create `@contact` and call `@contact.delay.send_contact_form` manually, the delayed job goes through the delayed job table and email is sent.

**Production Env - Webrick: OK**

- On the server if I start up a rails Webrick server I and enter the data for `@contact` via the web interface and then submit the job goes through the delayed job table and email is sent.

**Production Env - Nginx: ERROR**

- The application is currently served by Nginx.
- If I visit the interface via Nginx and enter the data for `@contact` and submit the page hangs.
- The Production Log gives the following error on the controller action, (referencing the line above):

> NoMethodError (undefined method `delay' for #< Contact:0x000000052962b0>) 
>   
>   
>   I have also confirmed that the versions of Rails, Ruby and the Delayed_Job_Active_Record and Daemons gems are the same in both environments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i've been stuck on this one for a while.  I want to find a solution that works with Nginx and which gives me the same functionality as 'Delayed Job'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with Unicorn/Nginx not being restarted upon deployment of code updates, leaving them with incorrect configurations.  The problem also occurred when adding Devise and other gems to the application.

The solution initially was to log into the VPS shell after a deployment, (via Capistrano) and run the following:

**Restart Unicorn:**

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_esg stop
/etc/init.d/unicorn_esg start
```

Where *unicorn_esg* is the Unicorn reference to the application used in my deploy.rb configuration.

**Restart Nginx:**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

The next step would be to incorporate this into the end of the deploy.rb script so it is automatically run at the end of each deployment.